# GoogleMap class not found Android Studio Gradle

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services

I am trying to create a new `GoogleMap` object in my map activity but the system cannot seem to find this class.

Other classes like `GoogleMapOptions` are there but i cannot seem to find this one, maybe my imports are just wrong...

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE**: display a marker on the map

here is my class:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private GoogleMap map; 

    public MapActivity(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }
}
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
}
```

And my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a new `GoogleMap` object.

When you create a `SupportMapFragment` you should get the `GoogleMap` object inside that fragment using something like below:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();
```